# What was Chancellor Palpatine watching in the theater?

Tags: star-wars, darth-sidious, revenge-of-the-sith

What was Chancellor Palpatine watching at the theater in this scene from *Revenge of the Sith*?

- Opera?
- Athletic competition?
- Academic conference?
- Performance art?

Please provide answers with quotes from canon sources.

Comment: "Now, watch the play Anakin. A thrilling tale, ‘The Ghostly Threat’. And here is the merry jester! Me-sah think you gonna *love* him."

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The (fully canon) factbooks [Star Wars in 100 Scenes](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_in_100_Scenes) and [Star Wars: Absolutely Everything You Need to Know](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Absolutely_Everything_You_Need_to_Know) identify it as a graceful *aquatic ballet* performed by a Mon Calamari troupe at the swanky [Galaxies Opera House](https://www.starwars.com/databank/galaxies-opera-house).

> Anakin meets Palpatine at the Galaxies Opera House, where **Mon Calamari
> dancers perform a ballet called "Squid Lake"**

The name 'Squid Lake' was based on the classic ballet 'Swan Lake', according to Lucasfilm concept artist Ryan Church:

> **Another scene that appeared challenging for CG artists was when gelatinous shapes performed what looked like an otherworldly Cirque du Soleil routine. Where did that idea come from?**
>
> **Ryan Church:** *The inspiration for that came on my birthday. My now-wife and I
> were going out to dinner and I got a call, which I rarely did, asking
> me develop ideas for a scene that George wanted to change. He wanted
> the scene to take place at a ballet or an opera. He said, **Think about
> it being Swan Lake, or Squid Lake with squid guys.** So I was thinking
> that we could do a space twist on a water ballet and have this giant
> ball of water in zero-gravity. So I sent these paintings over the next
> day and they ran with it.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Otherworldly Concept Designs of Ryan Church](https://www.awn.com/vfxworld/otherworldly-concept-designs-ryan-church)</sup></sub>
>
> [image]

Comment: I love that Calamari still means squid in Galactic Basic.

Comment: @Schrodinger'sStat and that Mon Calamari actually put up with being called that.

Comment: I don’t see General Ackbar anywhere in that. Such disappoint. @Schrodinger'sStat It appears that Disney Canon has tried to distance the name from the edible squids by renaming the planet’s exonym as Mon Cala (the endonym is still Dac, I think?). This looks like an etymological fallacy–based move, trying to separate _calamari_ into a ‘name’ _Cala_ and then _-mari_ because it’s an oceanic planet (our word _calamari_ is actually from a Graecolatin word meaning ‘pen case’, so nothing to do with oceans). So perhaps it doesn’t actually still mean squid in GB, at least not anymore.

Comment: The fact that a member of the production crew was thinking of *Swan Lake* when he came up with this concept makes me suspect they were borrowing ideas from the ballet.

Answer (score 27):

The [Mon Calamari Aquatic Ballet](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mon_Calamari_Aquatic_Ballet), performing Squid Lake, according to the Star Wars Wiki, which cites *Star Wars: Galactic Atlas* and *Darth Vader: Dark Lord of the Sith 13: Burning Seas, Part I* as its sources.

Comment: **Squid Lake** ballet? Is that a reference to the ballet, Swan Lake? The story of Swan Lake is about how an evil wizard corrupts a young woman and turns her into his pawn. Much like how Palpatine corrupts a young Anakin and turns him into his pawn. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swan_Lake

Comment: "Is that a reference to the ballet, Swan Lake?" Probably, but I don't know if any canonical sources explicitly state so.

Comment: @RichS No one is corrupted in Swan Lake. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swan_Lake#Prologue

Comment: @LVDV Thanks for clarifying that. The version of Swan Lake I saw had the evil wizard, Rothbart, corrupt Odette so she would do his bidding.